# Segmentation fault when running program

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, char

When I run this code I get an error *`segmentation fault (core dumped)`*. I see that the error lies in " printf("%c", first(s));", it seems that it is not the correct way to pass char/string to function? if not then what is the problem with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char first(char *str);
char first(char *str){
    int L=0;
    int a[127]={0};
    for (int i=0; i<127; i++){
      a[i]=i+1;
    }
    while (str != '\0'){
      for(int d=1; d<127; d++){
        if(str[L]==(char)d){
            if (a[L]>0){
                a[L]=0;
                L++;
                break;
            }
            else if(a[L]==0){
                a[L]=-1;
                L++;
                break;
            }
            else{
                L++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }        
  }
  for(int i=0; i>127; i++){
      if(a[i]==0)
          return (char)(i+1);
  }
  return '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char s="blazqnqbla";
  printf("%c", first(s));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong wording. The `core` dump is very probably not from your compiler, but when running the executable produced by compiling your source code. The bug is inside your program, not in the compiler. Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your character pointer is not declared properly. Change `char s="blazqnqbla";` to `char *s="blazqnqbla";`

Comment: 'while (str!= '\0')' is also problematic. You can't compare a char* to a char

Comment: try compiling with warnings `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, so cannot help with the algorithm.

To solve your core dump issue you need to do two things.

1. Define the character pointer as

   ```
   char *s="blazqnqbla";  // you had defined it as char s="..."
   ```
2. Change the while loop condition from `while (str!= '\0')` to

   ```
   while (str[L]!= '\0')
   ```

With these changes the program exits properly. There is still some algorithm problem with the function `first`. It is not giving any meaningful output.

Comment: yes, I see that it give a blank output, how to fix that?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do with this program. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you aiming to achieve with this code but this has lot of mistakes.

Exclusively for your `segmentation fault` error you will have to change initialization of `"s"` like 
`char *s="blazqnqbla";` or `char s[]="blazqnqbla";`
Since `s` is storing array of characters.

Also your code has infinite `while` loop
please modify that like  `while (str[L] != '\0')`